# Indentation doesn't match existing code (C#) in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I code in both C++ and C#.  In C#, since everything is in a class and is (at least usually) in a namespace, I don't indent for those, but start functions, declarations, etc. in line 1.  In VS 2010, the IDE would indent the first line in a class declaration as it thought appropriate.  I would move it back, and everything following would align with my preferences.

In VS 2015, every line is indented as if the containing function was indented as per the default, regardless, regardless of the actual indentation.  For instance, if I have the lines:

```
x = 1;
z = 3;
```

and add a line in the middle, it will auto-format as:

```
x = 1;
         y = 2;
z = 3;
```

(If I format the entire function by deleting and replacing the closing '},' the rest of the function will be shifted right so that everything matches the added line.)

I have the sinking feeling that this is a 'feature' that can't be changed. . . .

Comment: I've found a discussion of this issue at [https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4351].  There was some indication that at least a partial fix might be coming, but apparently not yet.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Tools | Options` dialog change the

```
Text Editor | C# | Tabs | Indenting
```

option from "Smart" to "Block"

You also need to tell VS to leave the lines/blocks of code alone when you type a `';'` or `'}'` character. Disable:

```
Text Editor | C# |Formatting | General | Automatically format statement on ;
Text Editor | C# |Formatting | General | Automatically format statement on }
```

You might also want to play around with the options in

```
Text Editor | C# | Formatting | Indentation
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried both "Smart" and "Block" and they appear to work the same (as does "None").  I have to turn off all formatting in order to stop the effect.

Comment: I see - I missed that you do need to also turn off `Text Editor | C# |Formatting | General | Automatically format statement on ;` and `Automatically format statement on }`.  Is that what you mean by turning off all formatting?  It seems like that's the behavior you want - I'm not sure how you can both have VS leave code alone and have it format a line or block when ';' or '}' are typed.  Those two desires are at odds.

Comment: I do not want VS to leave the code alone.  For example, when I insert a statement in the middle of a block, I DO want VS to format that statement (when I enter ';')-- but I want the added statement, after formatting, to have the same indentation as the other statements in the block (as occurred in VS 2010).  But it seems my only choices are to turn off formatting or to get incorrect formatting.

Comment: That makes sense.  I hope someone else can help; it's irritating when you have to fight your code editor.